# How can I automatically load a OSM data set into my rails postgresql db on rake db:create or migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis, openstreetmap

I am using Open Streetmap Data in my rails app. I have downloaded the relevant data as a .osm and can import that data into my db using osm2pgsql. So far no problem.

But how can i arrange the data to be imported automatically when I create the database? For example when I move the app to a production server, or when I just want to reset the database via db:drop.

Any help is appreciated.
Cheers,
Martin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it to your `db/seeds.rb` file.

Check this [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) for an insight. You probably will need to invoke the osm2pgsql from the command line.